# How to conditionally insert object to an array with the spread operator based on a string value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a `foo` and a `bar` object that both have an `id` prop:

```js
{ id: fooId, name: 'John' }
{ id: barId, name: 'Jane' }
```

I want to create an array `arr` of these objects but only insert the object to the `arr` if the `id` is not empty. I've tried this, but it leaves an empty object inside my array:

```js
const fooId = '';
const barId = '2021';
const arr = [
  ...[(fooId ? {id: fooId, name: 'John'} : {})],
  ...[(barId ? {id: barId, name: 'Jane'} : {})],
];

console.log(arr.length);
```

And I want `arr.length === 1` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return an array with an object, or an empty array if the id is empty, and spread it.

```js
const fooId = '';
const barId = '2021';
const arr = [
  ...fooId ? [{id: fooId, name: 'John'}] : [],
  ...barId ? [{id: barId, name: 'Jane'}] : [],
];

console.log(arr.length);
```

However, it's easier and cleaner to add the objects to the array, and then filter them out if the `id` is empty:

```js
const fooId = '';
const barId = '2021';
const arr = [
  {id: fooId, name: 'John'},
  {id: barId, name: 'Jane'},
].filter(o => o.id);

console.log(arr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
const fooId = '';
const barId = '2021';
const arr = [
  ...fooId && [{ id: fooId, name: 'John' }],
  ...barId && [{ id: barId, name: 'Jane' }],
];

console.log(arr);
```

Or like this one:

```js
const fooId = '';
const barId = '2021';
const arr = [
  fooId && { id: fooId, name: 'John' },
  barId && { id: barId, name: 'Jane' },
].filter(Boolean);

console.log(arr);
```